# Supporting Chinese traditional and Chinese simplified

Tags: c#, localization

As part of localization for our product we need to support both Chinese traditional and Chinese simplified but I see multiple cultures for these `zh-CN`, `zh-TW`, `zh-hans`, `zh-hant`. I don't want to create 4 folders with resource files in each folder. I want `zh-CN`,`zh-hans` to be same and `zh-TW`,`zh-hant` to be the same.

I created 2 folders with `zh-hans` and `zh-hant`, and the `ResourceManager` is automatically resolving `zh-CN` to `zh-hans` and `zh-TW` to `zh-hans`. Is there a documentation regarding this that the `ResourceManager` always does this mapping, I couldn't find any.

Comment: [`How do I write a good title?`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found various "Notes" on MSDN:

[CultureInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> A neutral culture is specified by only the two-letter lowercase
>   language code. For example, "fr" specifies the neutral culture for
>   French, and "de" specifies the neutral culture for German.
>
> There are two culture names that contradict this rule. The cultures
>   Chinese (Simplified), named zh-Hans, and Chinese (Traditional), named
>   zh-Hant, are neutral cultures. The culture names represent the current
>   standard and should be used unless you have a reason for using the
>   older names "zh-CHS" and "zh-CHT".

[CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture.aspx)

> The example uses the zh-CHS and zh-CHT culture names. However,
>   applications that target Windows Vista and later should use zh-Hans
>   instead of zh-CHS and zh-Hant instead of zh-CHT. zh-Hans and zh-Hant
>   represent the current standard and should be used unless you have a
>   reason for using the older names.
>
> Note also that the results of the example may differ on an
>   installation of Taiwanese Windows, where the input of a Chinese
>   (Traditional) neutral culture (zh, zh-CHT, or zh-Hant) will return
>   zh-TW.

[CultureInfo.Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.parent.aspx)

> The example displays the older zh-CHS and zh-CHT culture names with
>   the 0x0004 and 0x7C04 culture identifiers, respectively. However, your
>   Windows Vista applications should use the zh-Hans name instead of
>   zh-CHS and the zh-Hant name instead of zh-CHT. The zh-Hans and zh-Hant
>   names represent the current standard, and should be used unless you
>   have a reason for using the older names.