# Culture is not supported. Parameter name: name zh-hans-cn is an invalid culture identifier

Tags: asp.net

I have a multilanguage website running. I am not getting this error while testing locally. When I deploy the application in the running server, I am getting the above error only in some devices.

Please guide me how to fix this.?

I have searched a lot in google and not found a solution

Comment: this is the list of supported cultures in c#. http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/

Comment: But the above culture is not there in the list

Comment: Yes, because it is not support by default. Check this answer on SO to get more detailed information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180248/supporting-chinese-traditional-and-chinese-simplified

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I converted the above to zh-cn in my application and now it is working.