# Which culture code to use for Chinese string resource (resx) files?

Tags: wpf, localization, translation, cultureinfo

We're planning to translate our WPF desktop application to Simplified Chinese but I've noticed two similar culture codes: `zh-CN` and `zh-CHS`. What is the difference, and which resource file should we store the translated strings in: `foobar.zh-CN.resx` or `foobar.zh-CHS.resx` (or even both)?

Also, there are a couple of similarly named Windows "region" settings:

[image: region settings]

> 

[image: format settings]

> 

Which setting changes the UI culture (language/translation), and which setting changes the *non*-UI culture (date & number formatting)?

Comment: You probably want to use `zh-Hans`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19180802/1136211.

Comment: You may find the [ResXManager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager) helpful